# Connection to Oracle Database using JDBC and Python

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect my python code to an SQL database, I have an oracle driver and a jdbc database link and this is the code that we have so far but it definitely does not work please help! The first section of code is how we connected the database in java which worked but the second is our python version that doesn't work. We are hosting all our information

Java (connects):

```
public class PersonDao {
  // ORACLE JDBC Driver
  String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
  String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin: olandon/perry@spring2020.cjjvanphib99.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3234:ORCL";
      Driver driver;
      Connection connection;
```

Python (does not connect):

```
class PersonDao:
    def __init__(self):
      dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("spring2020.cjjvanphib99.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com", 3234, sid="orcl")
      connection = cx_Oracle.connect("olandon", "perry", dsn, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: What means 'does not work'. Do you have any error returned here?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an error, It just still won't connect, is it technically correct?

Comment: So how do you know that it is not connecting? It should either create an some connection object which can be later used (maybe there is some error?) or just raise anything.

Comment: No errors come up but when I click the link I was provided with it says not connected

Comment: Sorry, you need to be more specific - what link are you clicking? What says you're not connected?

Comment: It's a long time since I used a SID (they were obsoleted over a decade ago by service names), but were/are they case sensitive?  Try `sid="ORCL"`  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267752/is-an-oracle-sid-uppercase-or-lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your AWS RDS security group? You might need to enable port 3234 in the RDS security group

Comment: the port seems fine, im just wondering if I need to include my driver and how I would do that

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command below:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@IP:port/server_name')
```

Comment: If I correctly re-read what I wrote a while back in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#jdbc-and-oracle-sql-developer-connection-strings it looks like the poster is using a SID, not a service name, so the 'easy connect' syntax you show won't work (because easy connect strings only work with service names).